# determine if the relation is a function $f = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} : x\leq y \}$

Tags: calculus

determine whether the given relation is a function:
 $$f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}: x\leq y \}$$

Hello I am unsure how to do this. I know every $y$ has an $x$ but since $x$'s have multiple $y$'s I am unsure whether it is a real function.
My gut says yes, 
but I am also supposed to graph this which leads me to believe he might be tying to show that is supposed to be no.

Thank you.

As always, I'd rather understand it then have the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a relation $R$ is a **function** if:
$$(x,y), (x,z) \in R \Rightarrow y = z$$.

The condition is **not** satisfied for your example because $(1,2)\in R$, and $(1,3) \in R$, and $2 \neq 3$.